# How can one use a path alias in *.vue component imports in Vite?

Tags: vue.js, vite

When I work with Vue single file components in Vite I can use a *baseUrl* and *path* alias in *tsconfig.json* to import *.ts files into component files. However, the same does not work with imports of *.vue files because I get a run-time error.

```
// ts files: works fine
import { FooModel } from "@/models/FooModel"

// vue files: relative path works fine
import { FooComponent } from "./models/FooComponent.vue"

// vue files: path alias gives a run-time error!
import { FooComponent } from "@/models/FooComponent.vue"
```

There is a similar question on [Vite.js Discord Server](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/2016) but it has not been answered yet.

Therefore, my **main question** is: how can one get the path alias working for single file component imports in Vite?

The subquestion is who does the path resolving for *.vue files in Vite? With Vue CLI this is handled in webpack, if I am not mistaken, so in Vite it is rollup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this!

```
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import path from "path";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src") // map '@' to './src' 
    },
  },
});
```